# A comparison between the words port and harbor

Tags: comparison

Do the words "port" and "harbor" mean the same in marine terms? I looked these two words up in the NOAD dictioanary, and found:

[image]

Clearly, each one can have their own meaning – *harbor* can be used figuratively, for example. Also, *port* seems to be more focused on where you might find goods being imported and exported, while *harbor* seems to focus more on geographical shelter.

However, the part I'm most confused about is the part I've put in red. That makes it look like the word *port* could always be used in place of *harbor*.

Could all harbors also be considered ports, or vice-versa? The dictionary definition of *port* implies that the two words can be used to mean exactly the same thing. Is there something else I should know before I start using the terms interchangeably?

Comment: No; _port_ is the opposite of _starboard_; _harbor_ is not.

Comment: On hold, hmm. The linguistic interaction between these two words is much deeper than a dictionary! I offered significant edits to the answer that were apparently swallowed up by the closure vote.

Comment: @ScotM - In this case, I believe the closure vote was due in part to a slew of little-researched questions in a small span of time. (We try to get users out of the habit of using us instead of a dictionary.) I'll edit this question to make it more exemplary of a question that wouldn't get closed, and then reopen it. I hope you'll take the time to add what I think might be an informed and interesting answer.

Comment: Incidentally, it's funny: when I include research, the question often changes and becomes more focused, because I no longer need to ask about the things that are inherently obvious. In this case, consider how _harbor_ can be used more figuratively than _port_. That's clear from the dictionary, so there's no need to waste time explaining that in an answer. The question is no longer, "Do the words mean the same thing?" but, "Can I use _port_ in place of _harbor_?" People who answer must think more deeply, too. ***That's why we want O.P.'s to include such research when they ask the question***.

Comment: Makes sense, @J.R.

Comment: The edits I offered yesterday addressed that very issue. Have they disappeared altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Port is used in two senses in marine/nautical terms: the left side of a ship (as J.R. points out) and a place where a ship might stop and dock (could be an area of a city or the entire city/region could be referred to as a port). A port in this sense is usually an area where ships are loaded and unloaded of cargo.

A harbor is a place where a port might be found. It is generally a place where larger ships may safely approach land (no large rocks or underwater reefs) and where the waves and currents are calmer. This sense is sometimes used metaphorically for other safe places.

> He harbored his law-breaking brother in his house

OR

> This house was a welcome harbor for weary souls.

Comment: Agreed - I can think of only usage idiom with "port" which carries the sense safety: _"Any port in a storm."_  Other than that, the port is the commercial function of some harbors.  Not all harbors are ports, and not all ports have harbors.  (e.g. offshore oil and gas ports: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louisiana_Offshore_Oil_Port )

Comment: Or to put it another way, "harbor" is a description of the natural geography, while "port" is something made by people. Well, you can create an "artificial harbor" in the same way that you can create an "artificial lake", but still, "harbor" describes the dirt and rocks and shape of the land, while "port" means that there are docks and piers and often associated facilities.

Comment: Technically, @Jay, a harbor is not a matter of natural geography, but of human enhancements in bays, channels, and rivers, which are natural maritime *havens*.

Comment: @ScotM Hmm, are you speaking of a technical definition? Because for ordinary definitions, I checked a number of dictionaries, and all defined a harbor in terms of a place that is safe for ships because the water is deep enough and it is protected from winds and waves. The Wikipedia article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbor, makes an explicit distinction between natural and artificial harbors, similar to what I was trying to say. If there is such a thing as a "natural harbor", than that rather implies that a harbor is not by definition a man-made construct.

Comment: I see haven (in the nautical/marine sense) as equivalent to harbor. Haven is used in other more metaphorical senses. ex: "This park is a haven for endangered bears"

Comment: A "natural harbor" is a *bay* or a *channel*. I don't dispute the various uses of the word *harbor*, and by extension, the various definitions. I simply point out that the OED says, ... **especially** one protected from rough water by piers, jetties, and other **artificial structures**". I would suggest any natural haven from the sea **becomes** a harbor when people use it for a port.

Comment: I think you are using "especially" to mean something stricter than it does. Especially doesn't mean those not protected by piers, jetties and other artificial structures are not harbors.

Comment: @Jay "If there is such a thing as a "natural harbor", than that rather implies that a harbor is not by definition a man-made construct." Correct, it is no longer taken to be *by definition* man-made (though it was a long time ago). But you'd said "Or to put it another way, 'harbor' is a description of the natural geography," Wrong. It now **can be** a description of natural geography, but it can still refer to completely artificial structures too.

Comment: @JonHanna +1 I think a simple way is harbor describes shape where as port more describes function.

Comment: @eques yes, though originally *harbour* was all about function, its expansion to include natural features means it is now more about a shape that allows that function.

Comment: Well early harbors would have been more natural since the technology was more limited to build artificial ones. I was referring to the fact that port indicates its function as a place of trade for shipping etc, but harbor pertains to its shape (which makes it suitable as a refuge for ships).

Comment: @JonHanna "it CAN BE a description of natural geography, but it can refer to completely artificial structures too". Sure. I tried to say that in my comment. Yes, my comment was awkwardly worded. I think additional comments have cleared that point up. I'd be interested if there is someone on here with a nautical background who could make a definitive statement.

Answer (score 4):

The firm connection between *ports* and *harbors* arises from the human activity to enhance the convenience of natural *havens* used for shipping purposes. Early sea traders used bays, islands, and river mouths to protect themselves from violent weather and currents. When they found a safe place suitable for trade, they would develop that place for future trading.

In a *port*, the specific place where goods and people are unloaded from a boat is generally referred to as the [docks](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/dock). The entire **city** or **town**, which has been developed around the docks, is the ***[port](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/port)***:

> OED
>
> NOUN
>
> A **town** or **city** with a harbor where ships load or unload, especially one where customs officers are stationed.
>
> **Emphasis** mine

Which came first, the city or the port? In 2010, [***Port Shanghai***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_of_Shanghai), China, overtook Singapore and Hong Kong as the [*busiest **cargo** port in the world*](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-01-08/shanghai-surpasses-singapore-as-world-s-busiest-port-as-trade-volumes-jump.html). It was just a tiny agricultural village at the mouth of the Yangtze river until the Qing Dynasty developed it as a *port* between 1600 and 1900. It was a very desirable *port* for sea traders for two reasons:

> 1. The natural shelter of the [Hangzhou Bay](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Shanghai,+China/@30.7569808,121.0410762,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x35b27040b1f53c33:0x295129423c364a1) provided safe ***haven*** for ships.
> 2. The navigable Yangtze river provided easy access to interior ***commerce***.

### Shanghai

[image]

### Dover

[image]

The *dock* infrastructure and the *port* city of [Dover](http://www.doverport.co.uk/), England, the busiest **passenger** port in the world, also grew together near a large safe natural haven. In fact, most large coastal cities can attribute their current location to the maritime convenience of early sea traders, who chose safe natural ***havens*** for loading and unloading their cargo and passengers.

The **[etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=port&allowed_in_frame=0)** of *port* is ***rooted*** in the image of *moving from one place to another*:

> "*harbor*,"
>
> Old English *port* "*harbor, haven,*" reinforced by Old French port
>   "*harbor, port*; *mountain pass*;"
>
> Old English and Old French words both from Latin portus "*port,
>   harbor*," originally "*entrance, passage*," figuratively "*place of
>   refuge, assylum,*"
>
> from PIE *prtu- "*a going, a passage,*" from root **per*- (2) "*to lead,
>   pass over*"
>
> (**cognates**: Sanskrit parayati "carries over;" Greek *poros*
>   "*journey, passage, way*," *peirein* "*to pierce, run through*;" Latin
>   porta "*gate*, *door*," *portare* "*passage*," *peritus*
>   "*experienced*;" Avestan *peretush* "*passage, ford, bridge*;"
>   Armenian *hordan* "*go forward*;" Welsh *rhyd* "*ford*;" Old Church
>   Slavonic *pariti* "*to fly*;" Old English *faran* "*to go, journey*,"
>   Old Norse *fjörðr* "*inlet, estuary"*).

Eventually, [***port***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/port) becomes a synonym for *harbor*:

> OED
>
> 1.1 A *harbor*:

*Port* is a sensible **synonym** for *harbor* because the locations that serve to *move goods between land and sea* have natural land structures providing *safe haven* for ships to load and unload. Later, manmade *port* structures enhance the safety and convenience of the natural haven, turning it into a ***[harbor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/harbor)***:

> OED
>
> 1. A place on the coast where ships may moor in shelter, especially one protected from rough water by piers, jetties, and other artificial
>      structures:

Bays, islands and river mouths may provide *natural protection* and convenience for sea traders, but the word *harbor* emphasizes the manmade enhancements.

The [**etymology**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=harbor&allowed_in_frame=0) is **rooted** in the image of *lodging* and shifts to *refuge*:

> "*lodging for ships*,"
>
> early 12c., probably from Old English *herebeorg* "*lodgings, quarters*,"
>
> from *here* "*army, host*" (see harry) + *beorg* "*refuge, shelter*" (related
>   to *beorgan* "*save, preserve*;" see bury);
>
> perhaps modeled on Old Norse *herbergi* "*room, lodgings, quarters*."
>
> Sense shifted in Middle English to "*refuge, lodgings*," then to "*place
>   of shelter for ships.*"

This sense of *safe place* is included in the formal definition and is very much connected to the metaphorical use of ***[harbor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/harbour?q=harbor)***.

> 1.1 A place of refuge:
>
> Our orphanage is a *harbor* for children in distress.
>
> OR
>
> This house was a welcome *harbor* for weary souls.

Although they are deeply interconnected by the practical activities of shipping, the word *port* **emphasizes** the *commercial element of moving people and goods from one place to another*, while the word *harbor* **emphasizes** the *safe place for ships to stay*. The two ideas fit hand in glove.